# How to send TooManyAttempts in Dialog

Tags: botframework

Have this :

```
PromptDialog.PromptChoice<string>(new string[] { "opt1", "opt2", }, "You can choose : ", "Sorry, that wans't a valid option", 2);
```

But if the user didn't choose a valid option it throws an error :

> too many attempts

How to send TooManyAttempts as parameter in this promptdialog ?

I googled and i found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/10893730134135dd4af4250277de8e1b980f81c9/CSharp/Library/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L157) :

But i don't know how to send it directly from here.

Comment: You need to use the constructor in the PromptChoice that receives a PromptOption and then when you perform a new PrompOption the parameter string tooManyAttempts is the one that will need to have the new message...

Comment: Thank you. I solved this :)